# Xamarin Forms webview content not showing first time

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms

I'm working with `WebView` on Xamarin Forms 1.4.2
The problem I have seems to be a binding issue. But I'm not sure why this happens.

In my `OnAppearing()` event, I fetch data from SQLite Local Database and fill it into the WebView.

The content of webview is not been shown the first time the page loads.

I have a `ListView` under the WebView. On selecting any item in the listview the content of webview shows.

Has anyone experience this? Is there a work around?

i bind my webview directly to a HTML string :

```
webview.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
{
     Html = @"<html>
                    <head>
                          <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/>
                    </head>
                    <body height='100%'>"
                    + htmlstring
                    + @"</body>
               </html>"
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following example and it works for me.

Depending on what you do in the `OnAppearing` *you may have to wrap the update* using `Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{...});`.  I've included it, commented out, in the example below:-

**XAML:-**

```
<StackLayout>
    <WebView x:Name="webView1" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>    
    <Button x:Name="cmdLoadTestHtml1" Text="Load Test Html 1" Clicked="cmdLoadTestHtml1_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>
```

**Code Behind:-**

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //
        LoadTestHtml("OnAppearing....");
        //
        // Alternatively try this:-
        //Xamarin.Forms.Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        //    {
        //        LoadTestHtml("OnAppearing.");
        //    });
    }

    void cmdLoadTestHtml1_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadTestHtml("Button clicked");
    }

    void LoadTestHtml(string pstrSomeInnerContentToDisplay)
    {
        webView1.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
        {
            Html = @"<html>
                <head>
                      <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/>
                </head>
                <body height='100%'>"
                           + pstrSomeInnerContentToDisplay
                           + @"</body>
           </html>"
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because of your line

```
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/>
```

Correct it, or for now remove it and check after removing.

Comment: <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width; height=device-height; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;'/>

Comment: I have that. in my html `<head>`